# HTML5 input type number doesn't allow decimal

Tags: html, input

Have a form with an input type number. See my code below for the actual input.

```
<input min="0" placeholder="25.00" step="0.01" type="number">
```

Whenever I input a decimal, the input empties out. May just be having morning brain farts, but I have no clue what the issue could be? Tried changing step to 0.01 and same issue even though I didn't expect it to work in the first place. Issue is happening in Chrome so it's not specific to browser. I have checked all Javascript on our side and there is nothing that would be affecting the input. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you view / show the rendered html to us babyface :)

Comment: changed to rendered html @lordkain

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8L2fkwun/ works so must be something else

Comment: I have the same problem. You can see it in action here: http://vitalets.github.io/angular-xeditable/#html5-inputs. Just try edit the number field.